What do these yellow lines mean in this source code

How do i remove these lines, those are quite unpleasant to look at.

Hover the mouse over them; your IDE has a suggestion for improvement.

but what if i don't want the Android studio to show it? Is there any setting?

Does this answer your question? Flutter 2.5 update - const keyword on every static Widget

Those line are suggestions to improve performance or use of better suitable widgets for the case. Also named Linter.
When you hover your mouse on it OR press ctrl/cmd + . when the cursor is on them, it must show the issue/suggestion.
In that particular case it's probably suggesting that you could use const on those widgets (i.e: const TextField() )  to improve performance. Try putting const before the List that is passed to the column children. It will be like children: const [
To disable those you should edit a file named analysis_options.yaml located at the root of your project. There you can find many parameters to which the dart analyzer/linter will follow.
For that case the parameter you want is prefer_const_constructors: for which you will need to set to false.
example:
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
   rules:
      prefer_const_constructors: false

you can find more here https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules

what do i do if i want to disable that feature?

@Hrishi you would not want, as some of this suggestions are quite valuable. But if you still prefer to disable them it depends on the editor you use. Check the configuration of your editor (visual studio code or android editor or the one you use). You can hover over the suggestion and it usually gives a code, you search how to disable that suggestion with the code (deppends on your editor) or you can disable all of them but I highly don't recommend that

@Hrishi edited my answer with more context and how to disable that.

the yellow lines show that your value in your code is static and not in variable. ex: your label text is "E-mail address". to solve this, u can just put const at the beginning of the widget. in your case, try put const before the word 'Column'
